# Can you add a chrome extension in to a iframe, and if you can how?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to get some unblocked games on my school computer and one way I found out is to run them through an iframe. But I've been asked to add some cheats onto one of the games. So I need to somehow add a chrome extension onto an iframe. Help.

Edit: I don't want to create my own extension but I want to use one I found on GitHub. I also can't add any extensions on my school computer developer mode or not.
Here is the extension i want to use https://github.com/Kalaborative/survivio-plus

Comment: The question is vague/broad so I guess you want to write an extension that can access the contents of an iframe with the game inside. For that you'll need to declare a content script with `matches` for the game URL and `"all_frames": true`. Start with the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) and then see the documentation for the content scripts inside, and inspect the [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: I can't add any chrome extensions on my school computer so I have to use it in the page itself. Anyway I could do that.

Comment: No, extensions must be installed in the browser. The only method is probably the built-in devtools, if it's not disabled in your browser.